# Why can't use the variable in psql?

Tags: variables, psql

Login psql console to create new table:

```
\c ticker
ticker=# create table newtable as select * from sector  where sector.name='LED';
SELECT 38
Time: 63.221 ms
```

There are 38 rows record in the newtable:

```
ticker=# select count(*) from newtable;
 count 
-------
    38
(1 row)
```

Set the var as `LED` :

```
\set var LED
create table newtable as select * from sector  where sector.name=':var'; 
SELECT 0
Time: 44.697 ms
```

Nothing is in the newtable:

```
ticker=# select * from newtable;
 ticker | name 
--------+------
(0 rows)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table newtable as select * from sector  where sector.name=:'var';
```

Put the `:` before the quotes.